# Can't get featured image with WordPress REST API

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using WordPress REST API and can receive data from `https://websitename.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_fields=author,id,excerpt,title,link,featured_media_src_url`.

The problem is `featured_media_src_url` is added with [This WordPress Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api-featured-image/) and I can't retrieve it using URL filters. (it works by fetching just `.../w/v2/posts` without params)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the plugin gets the path using `featured_media` which returns an id. Adding this to the fields solves the problem:
`https://websitename.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_fields=author,id,excerpt,title,link,featured_media_src_url,featured_media`